# Generating all words of length N (N being prime) excluding isomorphic ones

Tags: algorithm, math, isomorphism, finite-group-theory

I would like to efficiently generate all words length **N** (N is prime) excluding isomorphic one.

Word **A** isomorphic to word **B** if there is an Automorphism for Finite Cyclic group with **N** elements that convert word **A** to the word **B**.

Let **V** - is an alphabet of **K** elements.

For example **V** = {a,b}

Let **N** is 7

Then, for example the word A = {a,a,a,b,b,a,a} is isomorphic to the word B = {a,b,a,a,a,a,b} and word C= {a,a,b,a,a,b,a}
because  Finite Cycle group S= {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} has automorphisms {0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3} and {0, 5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2}

The simplest algorithm is

- to find all possible words
- find all automorphism for Finite Cycle group with N elements (N prime)
- exclude isomorphic words

Unfortunately this way is not algorithmically efficient.

Comment: Can you explain how your definition of isomorphism differs from 'a permutation' for those less well versed in theory? Are there permutations that are not isomorphic or isomorphisms that are not permutations?

Comment: Or in other words - are two words isomorphic if they consist of the same number of each character (e.g., every word with 5 `a`s and 2 `b`s is isomorphic to each other)?

Comment: Word  A = {a,a,a,b,b,a,a} is not isomorphic to the word D = {a,a,a,b,a,b,a} because there is no item (permutation) in the automorphism group of the finite Cyclic group of order N

Comment: There are only K^N words and only N-1 automorphisms, so the overhead is mostly negligible.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m You are right. It is mostly negligible. But for me the effect is important.

Comment: You might be able co come up with a clever algorithm that is asymptotically better than O(K^N), but for practical values of N it is probably not going to work too well. I recommend asking at [cs.se] and/or at [cstheory.se].

Answer (score 0):

If your objection to the simple algorithm is needing to store all of the unique words, that's not necessary. For each of the K^N words, test whether it's lexicographically less than or equal to all of its isomorphs (canonical), and if so, return it.

We can do better by

- Generating all canonical (N−1)-letter suffixes and appending each all possible first letters.
- Generating (N−1)-letter suffixes by iterating the second position through the possible letters and generating suffixes where the other letters are not less than the second position before testing for canonicity as above.

We could go further but I'm suspicious about whether the added complexity would pay for itself.